# K3s no longer recognizes Liveness and Readiness Probes in Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I am redeploying a K3s deployment from a few months ago. Then, it worked fine, with no problems. However, when I try to deploy it now: I get the following error:

`Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "deployment.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.template.spec.livenessProbe", unknown field "spec.template.spec.readinessProbe"`

My .yaml for the deployment is unchanged, and looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vei-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: server-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server-pod
          image: myname/mydeployment:latest
          env:
          - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            value: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            value: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          ports:
            - name: grpc
              containerPort: 50051
      livenessProbe:
        exec:
          command:
            - grpcurl
            - -plaintext
            - localhost:50051
            - ping.Pinger/Ping
      readinessProbe:
        exec:
          command:
            - grpc_health_probe
            - -addr=:50051
```

I have linted the .yaml file, and their doesn't seem to be any problem on that end. Has the syntax for Liveness and readiness changed drastically over the past few months?

Comment: A `livenessProbe` is specific to a container. You have tried to set `spec.template.spec.livenessProbe`, when in fact you should be setting `spec.template.spec.containers.0.livenessProbe`.

Comment: Thank you, though I am afraid that I do not understand the difference syntactically. Is there any reason why it would stop working over the past few months?

Comment: The difference is that you're trying to define them outside of a container definition, which doesn't make any sense. That syntax shouldn't ever have worked; is there any chance you accidentally removed some indentation at some point?

Comment: That fixed the problem, I just have no idea how the indentation went away.

Comment: Though now the probes are giving me different errors: none of the commands are apparently on $PATH

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probes not found on $PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75367341/probes-not-found-on-path)

Comment: They were two different issues, one after the other, of which @larsks answered the first

Answer (score 0):

The probes were missing an indent, and needed to be indented four spaces so that they were defined as part of the container. Instead of in the question, the .yaml needs to be like so:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vei-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: server-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server-pod
          image: myname/mydeployment:latest
          env:
          - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            value: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            value: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          ports:
            - name: grpc
              containerPort: 50051
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - grpcurl
                - -plaintext
                - localhost:50051
                - ping.Pinger/Ping
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - grpc_health_probe
                - -addr=:50051
```